# What techniques can I use to improve my jump smash timing in badminton?

Tags: technique, training, badminton

Often I find it very difficult to time my jump exactly right, often jumping too late and then missing the shot entirely. What can I use / practice to ensure I time my jump correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rory mentioned, practice will help - this technique is considered to be fairly advanced. Repetition is needed to perfect your technique.

If you want some additional training tips, [one site](http://www.how-to-play-badminton.com/badminton-jump-smash.html) suggests:

> This badminton skill requires a lot of practice. It's not easy to do a
>   badminton smash in the middle of the air. It's very common to be
>   inaccurate in hitting the shuttle in mid air as well as losing your
>   balance as you land on the ground at the beginning.
>
> Keep practising until you have the accuracy and body balance.Also make
>   sure that you get the correct sequence. Aim - jump - extend your
>   non-racket arm and lift your legs up at the same time - then swing!
>
> At the start, don't jump too high to enable better body balance and
>   focus on the correct technique.
>
> If you want more power for your jump smash, read this page on
>   generating maximum power for a jump smash.
>
> Gradually increase your jump height over time as you get better at
>   this technique. But make sure you have good balance.
>
> You should possess strong badminton basics to perform this advanced
>   shot.
>
> If you're somehow not able to execute this technique well, review your
>   badminton basics (whether you're holding the racquet wrongly, whether
>   you're doing a full arm swing... etc).

There is also a mention of Peter Rasmussen's badminton [coaching video](http://www.badmintonlife.com/store/essentials-of-technique/), if you don't mind paying to learn from a championship level player.

Answer (score 5):

This might sound very unhelpful, but really the **only** solution is lots of practice.

Ideally, get a coach, who can help you improve more quickly, but either way, just be prepared to put in the hours. It will come.

Get a good partner to send you shuttles at consistent heights and positions, and plan for specific targets (eg back left corner, or opponent's head :-) and keep on smashing them. Watch where you make the errors (this is easiest with an observer, or ideally a coach) but you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

One tip is hitting the shuttle while travelling down in a jump. Never hit the shuttle while going up as it reduces your reaction time for next shot.

Comment: Even though it doesn't really help the timing issue the OP was after, I think this answer has a good point that might not be very obvious to an inexperienced player. (+1)

Answer (score -5):

Wait for the shuttle to reach you , use your left hand for contact with the shuttle , don't twist you wrist to much and get the right swing